# Ada initialization of controlled singleton variable

Tags: singleton, ada, static-members, static-initialization

I am trying to create a package with a singleton variable that is auto initialized.  If the singleton variable is not a controlled type, then the compiler doesn't complain, but when I make it controlled, I get the warning:"cannot call Initialize before body seen"

Followed by:
"Program error will be raised at run time."

So, I think the compiler wants the singleton variable to be hidden from child objects, but this is not what I want.  Here's my code:

```
with Ada.Finalization;

package static_member is
   type singleton_type is tagged limited private;

private
   type singleton_type is new Ada.Finalization.Limited_Controlled with record
      data_to_init: Natural;
   end record;

   overriding procedure Initialize(data: in out singleton_type);
   overriding procedure Finalize(data: in out singleton_type);

   --This is where I get the warnings.
   --I want singleton to be visible to child objects.
   singleton: singleton_type;
end static_member;
```

Then the package body is:

```
package body static_member is
   overriding procedure Initialize(data: in out singleton_type) is
   begin
      data.data_to_init := 0;
   end Initialize;

   overriding procedure Finalize(data: in out singleton_type) is null;
end static_member;
```

How would I create a singleton variable that is initialized, and ready to use by the time object instances begin to be created? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use the usual Ada implementation of the singleton pattern?  (I.e. hide the state in the package body.)

Comment: Because I want child objects to have the ability to read from this singleton.  I guess I can make an accessor function.

Comment: Actually, even if I move the singleton to the body, I get the same warning.

Comment: But did you move the singleton _after_ `Initialize` in the body?

Comment: Thanks Simon! That worked!

Comment: If you move the singleton to the body, you ought to use `pragma Elaborate_Body` in the spec.

Comment: Okay.  I will do that.  What does that tell the compiler to do?

Comment: If it's created at elaboration time, why does it have to be controlled?

Comment: IIRC `Elaborate_Body` forces elaboration of the body at the time of within the spec, so any initialization there is not missed by clients

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this question as posed is that - as the compiler said -
"cannot call Initialize before body seen"; that is, the place in the
program text where `Initialize` is called must be after the place in
the program text where the body of `Initialize` is found. This is a
(maybe historical) consequence of a desire for [one-pass
compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler#One-pass_versus_multi-pass_compilers).

Because the body of `Initialize` has to appear in the body of the
package (unless it's null, which is legal in Ada 2012), this means
that `singleton` can only be declared in the package body (*after* the
body of `Initialize`, of course).

This means that you need to provide access subprograms for use by
child packages: possibly

```ada
with Ada.Finalization;
package Static_Member with Elaborate_Body is
   type Singleton_Type is tagged limited private;
   function Singleton return access Singleton_Type;
private
   type Singleton_Type is new Ada.Finalization.Limited_Controlled with record
      Data_To_Init: Natural;
   end record;

   overriding procedure Initialize (Data: in out Singleton_Type);
   overriding procedure Finalize (Data: in out Singleton_Type);
end Static_Member;

package body Static_Member is
   overriding procedure Initialize (Data: in out Singleton_Type) is
   begin
      Data.Data_To_Init := 0;
   end Initialize;

   overriding procedure Finalize (Data: in out Singleton_Type) is null;

   The_Singleton: aliased Singleton_Type;

   function Singleton return access Singleton_Type is (The_Singleton'Access);
end Static_Member;
```

The reason for the `Elaborate_Body` is that, without it, the compiler
doesn't have to elaborate the package body before other, using,
packages that call package subprograms (e.g. `Singleton`): so

```ada
The_Singleton: aliased Singleton_Type;
```

with the implicit call to `Initialize` might not have happened (which
would lead to a `Program_Error` with a different cause, known in the
trade as "access before elaboration" or ABE).

---

That said, there are other approaches, which avoid the use of
`Ada.Finalization`. Your sample code doesn't show any particular
reason to use it, and indeed there's no point in overriding `Finalize`
(unless you want something to happen at program shutdown?)

One possibility (for a simple case) would be to declare
`Singleton_Type` with initialization:

```ada
type Singleton_Type is record
   Data_To_Init : Natural := 0;
end record;
```

An alternate would be to do the initialization in the package body:

```ada
package Static_Member with Elaborate_Body is
   type Singleton_Type is limited private;
   function Singleton return access Singleton_Type;
private
   type Singleton_Type is limited record
      Data_To_Init : Natural;
   end record;
end Static_Member;

package body Static_Member is
   The_Singleton: aliased Singleton_Type;

   function Singleton return access Singleton_Type is (The_Singleton'Access);
begin
   The_Singleton.Data_To_Init := 0;
end Static_Member;
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround that comes to mind: if dynamic memory is no obstacle, you could allocate the object in the body of the package and have an access instead of a regular instance for your children to see.

Comment: Dynamic memory is not a problem, my problem seems to be the time of creation of the object.  My aim is to create the singleton before any instance of the encompassing object, or its children can come into scope.

Comment: Wouldn't this idea (with a pragma Elaborate_Body in the spec) satisfy that?